# 'due': is not a member of 'uv_timer_s'

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Not able to install composer-cli@0.20

I'm having this error and following this [guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools). Installed node v8.14.0 in windows.

```
c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\composer- 
cli\node_modules\node-report\src\utilities.cc(421): error C2039
:'due': is not a member of 'uv_timer_s' 
[C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\composer- 
cli\node_modules\node
-report\build\api.vcxproj]
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Composer is not supported on windows, however it was possible to get it to work but it looks like newer versions of node have included a newer version of libuv which removed the `due` property therefore node-report won't compile against this version of node anymore. Your only 2 options are

- try to find an older version of node 8 that includes an older version of libuv where node-report does compile
- move to a linux environment.

It is possible to install composer on the windows subsystem for linux as well, but I would recommend not trying to use it to bring up hyperledger fabric using docker from that environment as this requires a lot of extra work.